# Can't make automake to use C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, autoconf, automake

I'm working on some project and it seems that I can't make automake script to use C++11.

In rootdir of my project I have file `Makefile.am` which look like this (it was automade by eclipse):

```
SUBDIRS=src
```

Then in /rootdir/src I have Makefile.am that looks like this:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS=-Wall -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -DVERSION=\"$(VERSION)\" -DPROG="\"$(PACKAGE)\""

bin_PROGRAMS = algatorc
algatorc_SOURCES = algatorc.cpp
include_HEADERS = Timer.hpp TestSetIterator.hpp TestCase.hpp ETestSet.hpp EParameter.hpp Entity.hpp ParameterSet.hpp AbsAlgorithm.hpp Log.hpp JSON.hpp JSONValue.hpp

lib_LIBRARIES = libAlgatorc.a
libAlgatorc_a_SOURCES = ParameterSet.cpp TestCase.cpp EParameter.cpp ETestSet.cpp TestSetIterator.cpp Entity.cpp Timer.cpp JSON.cpp JSONValue.cpp AbsAlgorithm.cpp
algatorc_LDADD=libAlgatorc.a
```

So, I added `-std=gnu++11` for C++11 support but I still get this error:

```
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"algatorc\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"algatorc\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"algatorc\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"algatorc\" -DVERSION=\"1.0\" -I.     -g -O2 -MT algatorc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/algatorc.Tpo -c -o algatorc.o algatorc.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:35:0,
                 from Log.hpp:281,
                 from algatorc.cpp:18:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
```

And from this error I can see that g++ doesn't use `-Wall -fPIC -std=gnu++11`  but I don't see why. It's using something completely else.
This is my configure.ac script which is located in rootdir of my project

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([algatorc], [0.1], [my_mail])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/TestCase.hpp])
#AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])

LT_INIT
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

# Checks for programs.

AC_PROG_CXX

# Checks for libraries.

# Checks for header files.
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stdlib.h string.h sys/time.h unistd.h wchar.h wctype.h])

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.
AC_CHECK_HEADER_STDBOOL
AC_C_INLINE
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

# Checks for library functions.
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_MKTIME
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([gettimeofday memset mkdir])

LIBS=-ldl

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

I have also tried to add `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11` to configure.ac script but error still occurs. Any idea how to fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x64, and Eclipse (Version: Mars Release (4.5.0))

Comment: *Always* add dialect options to the `$CXX` variable. As the error states, it requires both compiler and library support, and the `$CXX` dialect options also affect the linker, while adding the dialect to `AM_CXXFLAGS` only effects compilation. Invoke configure with : `./configure CXX="g++ -std=c++11" ...`, or `./configure CXX="clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ ...` for clang.

Comment: `CXX="g++ -std=c++11"` is broken. The only thing to put in `CC` or `CXX` is the compiler. Even something like `CXX="g++ -m32"` or `CXX="g++ -m64"` breaks a significant number of configure programs (speaking from experience).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test shows that everything is working correctly for me, with a similar configuration, so you're going to have to figure out what's going on with your Makefile simply by rolling up your sleeves, looking into your final `Makefile`.

Look inside the automake-d `Makefile`. You should find somewhere inside it, the final build rule for .cpp.o. Search for ".cpp.o". It should look something like this:

```
.cpp.o:
    $(AM_V_CXX)$(CXXCOMPILE) -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo -c -o $@ $<
    $(AM_V_at)$(am__mv) $(DEPDIR)/$*.Tpo $(DEPDIR)/$*.Po
```

After verifying this, the next step is to look at what your `CXXCOMPILE` macro is defined to. It should look something like this:

```
CXXCOMPILE = $(CXX) $(DEFS) $(DEFAULT_INCLUDES) $(INCLUDES) \
    $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(AM_CXXFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)
```

And that's your `AM_CXXFLAGS` variable being used. Finally, confirm how it's defined in the actual `Makefile`.

In my case, for my simple test, it was simply:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = -std=gnu++11
```

In my case, it was just that, in your case, obviously you'll have your other flags in there.

That's it. The automake-d Makefile is obviously quite large, and looks intimidating, but when you get down to it, it's not very complicated at all.

It's going to be one of two things. Either another part of your Makefile.am clobbers the value of `AM_CXXFLAGS`, or the `CXXCOMPILE` macro is clobbered. One thing about automake, is that it generally doesn't complain if a macro or a variable is redefined. It'll simply generate the final `Makefile` using the final value of the variable. So, I would guess that somewhere later, in your Makefile.am, you set `AM_CXXFLAGS` to something else, without being aware of it here.

Note: the actual macros often get tweaked, with each successive version of `automake`, so yours may look slightly different, but the general idea should be the same. The `.cpp.o` build rule runs the `CXXCOMPILE` macro, which uses `AM_CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: It looks that problem is in src directory. It seems that Makefile isn't generated for that directory. Only for project root.

Comment: I've got it! I had this line in configure.ac `AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])` but my source files are in src. So I've changed this line to `AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])` and now is everything working. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `automake` will not generate `Makefile` until executing `automake`

> So, I added -std=gnu++11 for C++11 support but I still get this error:

```
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"algatorc\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"algatorc\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"algatorc\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"algatorc\" -DVERSION=\"1.0\" -I.     -g -O2 -MT algatorc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/algatorc.Tpo -c -o algatorc.o algatorc.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/thread:35:0,
             from Log.hpp:281,
             from algatorc.cpp:18:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
^
```

- Your log said there is no statement of `-std=gnu++11` in gcc`s compile time. In other words, `automake` didn't generate `Makefile` containing statement of `-std=gnu++11`.

So, all you need to do is, in your project root with command line:

```
$ autoreconf
```

This will automatically execute `aclocal`, `autoconf`, `automake` and blah blah...

- About checking the `-std=c++11` flag

is good to use [ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html)
To use it, you need to download it from the above link and set it in **$(project_top)/m4/**
Next, you write like below in **configure.ac**:

```
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11([noext], [mandatory])
```

And exec, you can check it's possible or not to use C++11 feature in the platform

```
$ autoreconf -vi -I m4
$ ./configure
```

Comment: automake auto-generates build-rules that will self-rebuild Makefile when anything in Makefile.am changes. So, if he added AM_CXXFLAGS to Makefile.am, make should've automatically regenerated the Makefile.